# How to switch the web browser to fullscreen mode with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a web application and to improve the user experience I wish to switch the browser in fullscreen mode. Any ideas how to do this (except asking the user to do it himself)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121475/javascript-automatically-maximize-browser-window-and-switch-to-full-screen-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible using the [FullScreenApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode), which is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen) at least in Chrome 27, FF 21, Safari 5.1 and Opera 16. It will be also supported by IE 11. There is also a minor [wrapper](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/) for API.

Answer (score 1):

```
Javascript.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. If you really want it, you have to open a new window:

var win = window.open('html.file', 'Name', 'fullscreen=true');

Comment: Indeed this is not possible for security reasons. I don't wish to do automatic fullscreen, but triggering by clicking on a button. Seems that the only way to enter fullscreen mode is by pressing F11.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do full screen but you can just resize the window to the available width and height of the screen.