# Is there a way to fullscreen a browser window using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)

I am designing a web app with the front-end in javascript and jQuery. It would make sense for the app to take over the client's entire screen (not to be confused with just the browser's viewport). Essentially, I would like the user to be able to click a button to enter into this fullscreen mode. (If you are aware of Netflix's fullscreen mode, that's the functionality I'm looking for.)

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I might implement this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen

Comment: or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155867/how-to-switch-the-web-browser-to-fullscreen-mode-with-javascript

Answer (score 3):

no way, josé!

This is a security feature to prevent spam and spoofing.
It's up to the user to put his browser in fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1):

If that were possible without user intervention it would be a major security problem. Flash has a very controlled version of this which is only able to be triggered as a result of user input. I think that is what Netflix uses?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.resizeTo

Comment: That's only able to resize the window, not actually toggle fullscreen mode, which hides things like the underlying operating system's menu bars, the browser's address bar, and a load of other things.

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible you would see it happen all the time with intrusive advertisements. Let's hope it remains impossible.