# How to show a child window full-screen mode?

Tags: javascript, dom, popup

I'm opening a child window through the parent window, and I want the child window to be displayed in full-screen mode.

Comment: Who honestly downvoted this question lol? It's a valid question for someone who doesn't realize the security implications. I'm upvoting as it's a fair and properly phrased question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to maximize the browser window to full-screen with JavaScript. This is considered a security restriction.

Sources:

- [Stack Overflow - How to make in Javascript full screen windows (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-in-javascript-full-screen-windows-stretching-all-over-the-screen)
- [Stack Overflow -  To view the silverlight app in fullscreen mode(F11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164078/to-view-the-silverlight-app-in-fullscreen-modef11)
- [SitePoint Forums - Trigger F11 using javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=632704#)
- [Webmaster World - F11 Fullscreen using Javascript](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4170.htm)

---

The only workaround is to change the window size to fill the whole screen, as in the following example:

```
window.moveTo(0, 0);
window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

However note that this is not really full-screen mode -- just a maximized window.